# Positive definite matrix with entries bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B(\cdot , \cdot)$ be a  bilinear form on the Hilbert space $V$. 
Let $V_h$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $V$ with basis $\{\varphi i\}$, $i  =1,\dotsc,N$.

I want to show that that the resulting coefficient matrix $A$ defined by
$A_{i,j} = B(\varphi j , \varphi i)$ is positive definite.

I know that $i$ have to show that $x^{T}Ax$ is positive but I can not compute it.

Comment: It seems that $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ should be positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the hypothesis that $B$ is positive definite.

What is your definition of a positive definite bilinear form on a Hilbert space?  Whatever it is, it should immediately imply the inequality you seek for any vector in the Hilbert space.  So it follows for any vector in any subspace.  Thus the matrix of the bilinear form restricted to a finite dimensional subspace should also be positive definite.

Comment: Here what i have for the bilinear form and it is not neccesary positive. A (real) bilinear form on a real Hilbert space H is a map from H×H into R denoted
by B(f, g) for f, g ∈ H, which satisfies:
B(λ1f1 + λ2f2, g) = λ1B(f1, g) + λ2B(f2, g)
B(f, μ1g1 + μ2g2) = μ1B(f, g1) + μ2B(f, g2)
for fi, f, gi, g ∈ H, μi, λi ∈ R.

Comment: @blackjack If your bilinear form is not itself positive definite, then you have no hope.  Consider, for example, the hilbert space $\mathbb{R}$ and the bilinear form $B(x,y)=-xy$.  This is certainly a bilinear form on a Hilbert space (check it!), but its matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \end{bmatrix}$, which is certainly not positive definite.